# Sorting Based on Rating

Tags: st.statistics

I'm doing some machine learning stuff and I want to take some random samples and determine if a human agrees with the computer.  To do this a user just votes up or down on a given item.  Then I want to be able to sort by the items with the highest rating.  I want to use something more complicated than simply up-down to get good results.

I've looked into the [Wilson Interval Score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) and it seems like a decent solution, but I'm wondering if there are other alternatives.

I'm going to be using C# 4.0 if that matters but for now I'm strictly interested in the math.

Example below:

Lets suppose I have 3 items and multiple people have voted on them according to the table:

```
Item    Up    Down
1       6       1
2       60      11
3       100     40
```

In this example I would like Item 3 to be listed first, item 2 second and 3 third.  This is a rough approximation of my expectations.

Item 3 has the most responses and highest relative approval.  Item 2 has more responses than Item 1 despite having a lower percentage approval.

I'm trying to list the items in terms of some sort of relative metric and algrotithm without using something like percent approval or net score; something more complicated.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6019/calculating-the-most-helpful-review

Comment: maybe you mean something like 250/40 or at least 241/40 for line 3?

Answer (score 2):

For the question as posed, the binomial model (Wilson Interval Score) is indeed a good approach.

However you should bear in mind that the votes are not independent events (as a binomial model supposes). You could do better by considering *who* is voting, and possibly also, who is viewing the list. That opens up a more complex range of models.

Collaborative filters are worth a look as a simple personalised ratings model. Beyond that, you get into designing a probability model to describe users and what they like, then fitting it to the data (e.g. by using the Newton-Raphson method to find the maximum likelihood).